# Check if a user input is NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I am trying to write a small program, and I have 3 conditions for the program to proceed.

1. prompt user input again if hour > 12
2. prompt user input again if hour < 1
3. prompt user input again if hour === NaN
   (I am stuck with the 3rd condition)

Here is the code I wrote to cope with 1st 2 conditions and unable to do the 3rd.

```
let hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Hour'));

while (hour > 12 || hour < 1) {
    hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Valid Hour'));
}
```

i am pretty new to coding.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for `isNaN(hour)`

Comment: May I suggest you change the title, as your question does not seem to be related to the `while` loop but it is actually about how to check for `NaN` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```
let hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Hour'));

while (hour > 12 || hour < 1 || isNaN(hour)) {
    hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Valid Hour'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Hour'));

while (hour > 12 || hour < 1 || isNaN(hour)) {
    hour = parseInt(prompt('Enter Valid Hour'));
}
```